# Connecting WDDL via C#

Tags: c#, wsdl

I mean I've hit a dead end with My reseach.
I want to send request and get respone.

WHat I got:
project --> add link --> http://xx:xx:xx:xxxx/AppServer/IEtranSysservice
I got Interface.
I am not able figure it out. What should I do?

```
namespace WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice {


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys")]
public interface IEtranSys {
    
    // CODEGEN: Контракт генерации сообщений с пространством имен упаковщика (SysEtranInt) сообщения SendBlockRequest не соответствует значению по умолчанию (http://tempuri.org/).
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:SysEtranInt", ReplyAction="*")]
    WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockResponse SendBlock(WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockRequest request);
    
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:SysEtranInt", ReplyAction="*")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockResponse> SendBlockAsync(WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockRequest request);
    
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:SysEtranInt", ReplyAction="*")]
    WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockResponse GetBlock(WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockRequest request);
    
    // CODEGEN: Идет формирование контракта на сообщение, так как операция может иметь много возвращаемых значений.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:SysEtranInt", ReplyAction="*")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockResponse> GetBlockAsync(WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockRequest request);
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="SendBlock", WrapperNamespace="SysEtranInt", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class SendBlockRequest {
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=0)]
    public string Text;
    
    public SendBlockRequest() {
    }
    
    public SendBlockRequest(string Text) {
        this.Text = Text;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="SendBlockResponse", WrapperNamespace="SysEtranInt", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class SendBlockResponse {
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=0)]
    public bool @return;
    
    public SendBlockResponse() {
    }
    
    public SendBlockResponse(bool @return) {
        this.@return = @return;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetBlock", WrapperNamespace="SysEtranInt", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class GetBlockRequest {
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=0)]
    public string Login;
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=1)]
    public string Password;
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=2)]
    public string Text;
    
    public GetBlockRequest() {
    }
    
    public GetBlockRequest(string Login, string Password, string Text) {
        this.Login = Login;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.Text = Text;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetBlockResponse", WrapperNamespace="SysEtranInt", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class GetBlockResponse {
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=0)]
    public bool @return;
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=1)]
    public string Text;
    
    public GetBlockResponse() {
    }
    
    public GetBlockResponse(bool @return, string Text) {
        this.@return = @return;
        this.Text = Text;
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface IEtranSysChannel : WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class EtranSysClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys>, WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys {
    
    public EtranSysClient() {
    }
    
    public EtranSysClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }
    
    public EtranSysClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }
    
    public EtranSysClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }
    
    public EtranSysClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }
    
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockResponse WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys.SendBlock(WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.SendBlock(request);
    }
    
    public bool SendBlock(string Text) {
        WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockRequest inValue = new WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockRequest();
        inValue.Text = Text;
        WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockResponse retVal = ((WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys)(this)).SendBlock(inValue);
        return retVal.@return;
    }
    
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockResponse> WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys.SendBlockAsync(WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.SendBlockAsync(request);
    }
    
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockResponse> SendBlockAsync(string Text) {
        WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockRequest inValue = new WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.SendBlockRequest();
        inValue.Text = Text;
        return ((WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys)(this)).SendBlockAsync(inValue);
    }
    
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockResponse WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys.GetBlock(WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.GetBlock(request);
    }
    
    public bool GetBlock(string Login, string Password, ref string Text) {
        WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockRequest inValue = new WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockRequest();
        inValue.Login = Login;
        inValue.Password = Password;
        inValue.Text = Text;
        WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockResponse retVal = ((WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys)(this)).GetBlock(inValue);
        Text = retVal.Text;
        return retVal.@return;
    }
    
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockResponse> GetBlockAsync(WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice.GetBlockRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.GetBlockAsync(request);
    }
}
```

}

I got Intefece I have to realize it:
What I did:

What am I doint wrong?
**Try to get something**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web;
    using WebApplication1.IEtranSysservice;

    namespace WebApplication1.GetRequest
{
    public class EtranConnect : IEtranSysservice.IEtranSys
    {

        public GetBlockResponse GetBlock(GetBlockRequest request)
        {
         
            GetBlockRequest ce = new GetBlockRequest("Login","Pass",Text);
            return ce;
        }

        public Task<GetBlockResponse> GetBlockAsync(GetBlockRequest request)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public SendBlockResponse SendBlock(SendBlockRequest request)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<SendBlockResponse> SendBlockAsync(SendBlockRequest request)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

UPD:

```
  EtranConnect ec = new EtranConnect();
  IEtranSysservice.GetBlockRequest getblock = new 
  IEtranSysservice.GetBlockRequest("Login", "Pas",Text);
            ec.GetBlock(getblock);

    public GetBlockResponse GetBlock(GetBlockRequest request)
    {
        //GetBlockRequest ce = new GetBlockRequest("Login","Pass","Text");
        GetBlockResponse getBlockResponse = new GetBlockResponse(true, request.Text);
        return getBlockResponse;
    }
```

Cannot get response

Comment: You have a controller where you are sending a request from a client to server and the server is responding with an xml results.  Your design is proper.  The controller uses xml deserialize to parse the xml response.  The action results is the root class that the controller uses to parse.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

Comment: I have corret XML request. Imagine Text = Correct XML request

Comment: if it nessecary I can show XML request

Comment: The best way is to read up on Controllers.  If you have a specific question I can answer.  You posted the XML classes that are used by the controller to parse the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could  solved it. NVM

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        XmlDocument str = CreateXML.xDoc();
        EtranConnect ec = new EtranConnect();
        IEtranSysservice.GetBlockRequest getblock = new IEtranSysservice.GetBlockRequest(Login,Pass, str.InnerXml);
        ec.GetBlock(getblock);
        return View();
    }
 public GetBlockResponse GetBlock(GetBlockRequest request)
        {
            EtranSysClient etranSysClient = new EtranSysClient();
            etranSysClient.GetBlock(logg, pass, ref request.Text);
            GetBlockResponse getBlockResponse = new GetBlockResponse(true, request.Text);
            return getBlockResponse;
        }
```